# Ruby: add object to the end of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enumerable

I have two objects @tracks (an enumerable) and @artist, and I'd like to create an enumerable with all the tracks and the artist in them.  This is so that I can pass them to a method which will do (each track, and the artist have change events):

```
change_events = object.map(&:change_events).flatten
```

My idea was:

```
objects = @artist.tracks
objects << @artist
```

but that gives me this error for the second line (which makes sense, but I don't know how to fix):

```
Track(#17816) expected, got Artist(#17572)
```

Any ideas on how I could do this would be appreciated!

Comment: is tracks a dependent table, eg an Artist has many tracks, or a list of tracks in a tracks column on the artist table?

Comment: an artist has many tracks.  etarion's solution works great, though!

Comment: @tiswas: artist.tracks gives you a Rails Relation, do artist.tracks.all to get it as an array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This (the error) signals that it (the return value of `@artist.tracks`) is not an array you are dealing with, but some rails-specific data type. You could try

```
objects = @artist.tracks.to_a
objects << @artist
```

But using inhomogeneous values in an array is often not good, if they all respond to the method you need you should be good though.